# Ionic release apk increases file size with every build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm new to **Ionic** and have written my first Android application.

There is no extra package/library installed and there is only one page that too not too heavy.

When I build first release

```
cordova build android --prod --release
```

The filesize generated was **3.x mb**
I added a minor change and generated a new release but this time, the filesize is **7.x mb**

Here is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "author": "Anuj Sharma",
  "homepage": "http://anujsh.in/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

and the content of only homepage **home.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

    public phoneNumber: string;
    public errorMessage: string | null;

    public inputForm: FormGroup;
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private platform: Platform
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.inputForm = this.fb.group({
            phoneNumber: new FormControl('', [
                Validators.required
            ])
        });
    }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
            navigator['app'].exitApp();
        });
    }

    ionViewWillLeave() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    start() {
        let phoneNumber = this.inputForm.value['phoneNumber'];

        if (!phoneNumber) {
            this.errorMessage = 'Phone number required';
            return;
        }

        // Remove white spaces and +
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/\s/g, '').replace('+', '');

        const url = this.web + phoneNumber;

        window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
    }
}
```

This much is only the content still filesize is more than 7 mb.

Comment: Delete www folder and tried because if you delete some files from src > assets those are not deleted from www so go and delete www folder and make new build. That was the one reason might be.